# Is it possible to delete a hudson job programmatically via REST API?

Tags: hudson

I can create jobs using /createItem?name=JOBNAME, but cant find anything in the docs about deleting jobs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Discovered by looking into how the delete button does it that you can just post to joburl/doDelete a bit like this..

```
wget -qO- --post-data="anything" http://HOST/job/JOBNAME/doDelete > /dev/null
```

Comment: If you go to `http://HOST/job/JOBNAME/doDelete` in the browser Jenkins conveniently allows you to perform the post from there as well!

Answer (score 8):

Go to `<JobURL>/api/?` You will get below text.

> **Delete a job**
>
> To programmatically delete this job,
>   do HTTP POST to this URL.

DISCLAIMER: I tested it with Jenkins. But this should also work in Hudson.