# Is it possible to have multi-config template in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a number of multi-config jobs and all have to run on the same machines, one after another.

For example:

1. Build on all platforms.
2. Do some automated testing.
3. Do some automated benchmarking.

These are all happening on the same machines, in that order, but they are different jobs.

The problem is that if I want to add another platform or remove one of them, I will have to do it for every single multi-config job. What I would like is to have a way of defining those platforms in one place and then have the jobs point to that template and run.

I am quite sure I'm not the first one to hit this problem and that there should be some plugin out there, but I haven't been able to find it.

So, is there any simple way of doing this?

Comment: You could have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788535/copy-jenkins-multijob-job-and-all-its-downstream-jobs-via-groovy-job .
It probably does not fit your setup, but with a bit of tweaking it might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

We create temaplte jobs in jenkins which helps us to create all the set of jobs reqired for a platform, we just pass the platform / component name as input pareamter for the template job. We us the job copy plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jobcopy+Builder+plugin

But for a deleting the jobs we have another job where again the component name is the input parameter and we use something similar to the answer given here [Is it possible to delete a hudson job programmatically via REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099139/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-hudson-job-programmatically-via-rest-api)

Comment: This is quite interesting, but I am not sure that it does exactly what I asked for. Does this provide the ability of creating a single matrix that you can share across multiple jobs? I want to be able to change the matrix in a single place and then have it propagate to all my jobs. Copy/pasting means that if I want to take a machine down, then I have to edit every single job.